# Parsing deep JSON in Objective c for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am trying to parse following JSON that is generated dynamically by a PHP script.

```
{
"a": [
    {
        "key": "albatross",
        "value": "Albatross"
    },
    {
        "key": "ant",
        "value": "Ant"
    },
    {
        "key": "abyssinian",
        "value": "Abyssinian"
    }
],
"b": [
    {
        "key": "bat",
        "value": "Bat"
    },
    {
        "key": "badger",
        "value": "Badger"
    }
],
"e": [
    {
        "key": "elephant",
        "value": "Elephant"
    },
    {
        "key": "eagle",
        "value": "Eagle"
    },
    {
        "key": "elephant_seal",
        "value": "Elephant Seal"
    }
],
"g": [
    {
        "key": "gar",
        "value": "Gar"
    },
    {
        "key": "gorilla",
        "value": "Gorilla"
    }
],
"k": [
    {
        "key": "kangaroo",
        "value": "Gar"
    },
    {
        "key": "kiwi",
        "value": "Kiwi"
    },
    {
        "key": "koala",
        "value": "Koala"
    },
    {
        "key": "kudu",
        "value": "Kudu"
    }
]
```

}

I have following code so far but the resulted table index repeats some data and also the index on right does not function. (output screenshot below)

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self fetchJSONFromURL];

    }

    - (void) fetchJSONFromURL{
        NSString *str=@"http://myjsonurl.com/myjson.php";
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSError *error=nil;
        jsonResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                     NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        totalJsonNodes = [jsonResponse count];

        animalsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        animalsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        for ( NSDictionary *values in jsonResponse )
        {

            NSArray *animals = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:values] valueForKey:@"key"];

            for (NSObject* o in animals)
            {
                [animalsArray addObject:o];
                //[animalsDictionary setObject:o forKey:values];

            }

            sortedValues = [animalsArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

        }

        NSLog(@"%@", sortedValues);
        //set the keys for the right side index
        keys = [[jsonResponse allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return [jsonResponse count];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSString *key = keys[section];


        for ( NSDictionary *values in jsonResponse )
        {
             NSArray *animals = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:values] valueForKey:@"key"];

            if([values isEqual:key]){
                return animals.count;
            }

        }

        return [jsonResponse count];
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        int count = 0;
        NSLog(@"total json nodes : %d", totalJsonNodes);
        for ( int i =0; i < totalJsonNodes; i++)
        {
            if(count == indexPath.section){
                //NSLog(@"indexPath.section: %d  indexPath.row %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
                NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %d  count %d", indexPath.row, count);
                int objectIndex = indexPath.row + count +i;
                cell.textLabel.text = [sortedValues objectAtIndex:objectIndex];

            }

            count++;

        }

        return cell;
    }

    -(NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        return keys;
    }
```

[image: UITableVIew test app screenshot][image]

As you can see in the screenshot, few words are repetaed and few are missing (for index of 'k') and with the code above small alphabetic index on right only works for first three letter and does not work for g and k.

It would be great if someone can let me know where in the code I have problem.

Comment: What do you see when you log `sortedValues`?  I'm guessing that list is OK and it's being mucked up when the tableview is built.

Comment: sorted value log gives a sorted list e.g. abyssinian, albatross, ant, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not write code to do this stuff but you should use libraries that have been written and tested by hundreds of developers. They work asynchronously for better performance. The one you should use here is called [RestKit](http://restkit.org). It's super fast, flexible, and easy to use. But more importantly it just works.

```
//Create object manager
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_BASE_URL]];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;


//Map your object to a class
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SomeClass class]];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"customerID",
                                         @"firstName",
                                         @"lastName",
                                         @"emailAddress",
                                         @"phoneNumber"
                                                ]];

//add a response descriptor with your map
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:URL_CUSTOMER_REGISTER keyPath:@"success" statusCodes:nil];

//add it to the object manager
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

//And now the async request
NSDictionary *requestParam = @{
                               @"customerID": self.theCustomer.customerID,
                               @"customerPassword": self.theCustomer.customerPassword
                               };


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:URL_RESTAURANTS parameters:requestParam success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {   

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: would you be able to write a simple basic code to get JSON without authentication using restKit?, all the code out there is based on authentication which my service doesn't need.

Comment: Restkit can authenticate but you certainly don't need to. All it does is pull JSON and convert it into NSObjects. This is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't understood your comment. I added a bit of code.